# Remove contacts from a journey in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, campaign, distributed-marketing

I have created a journey with No re-entry setting. Contact have been injected into it through a process we did not want. We cannot create a new journey as this journey is connected with a campaign in CRM through distributed marketing. Is it possible to remove all injected contacts in this journey? Journeys are stopped now and we are trying to create new version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use REST API route - POST /interaction/v1/interactions/contactexit

The catch here is it Removes up to 50 contacts from a journey in one request.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/contactExitRequest.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify why you need to remove them and not just create a new version and stop the old one?

Seeing that you point out there is no re-entry, I'm guessing you want to inject the same subscribers into the journey again but in the new version?